# ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, newline, strip

How do I get this to work?

```
n = 1234
f = open("file", "r")
while True:
 x=f.readline()
 print "*********************"
 print n%(long(x))
 if n%(long(x))==0:
   print x
else:
 print "..."
```

I'm a noob in python and I'm getting an error I don't understand. What am I doing wrong?

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: What's in this file named `file`?

Comment: It is usually a good idea to describe in words what you are trying to accomplish with your code, so it takes less time to understand how to help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [104]: long('')
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''
```

This error is telling you that `x` is the empty string.

You could be getting this at the end of the file.
It can be fixed with:

```
while True:
    x = f.readline()
    if x == '': break
```

Answer (score 0):

A `try/except` block can be a handy way to debug things like this

```
n = 1234
f = open("file", "r")
while True:
 x=f.readline()
 print "*********************"
 try:                                              # Add these 3 lines
     print n%(long(x))
 except ValueError:                                # to help work out
     print "Something went wrong {!r}".format(x)   # the problem value
 if n%(long(x))==0:
   print x
else:
 print "..."
```